# How to format <section> elements in HTML5 to provide meaningful insight to assistive device users?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

What is the best way is to have a screen reader type assistive device announce sections in an insightful way?

Ideally, rather than passing this job onto a child `<h1>` tag is there a way to mark up the actual `<section>` tag that can serve this purpose?

Where an `<article>` is broken into `<section>`s the idea is that `<section>`s are not suitable for syndication but they should still have their own inherent identity within the document structure. How do we as HTML authors document this?

Example: given this tree:

```
Article: A review of the iPad
section: brief preamble, statement of goals
section: aesthetics
section: performance
section: target market
section: wrap up
```

How do we mark up the `<section>`s to empower assistive devices to pluck the section focus from the `<section>` tag?

Here's an example in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <!-- meta data and css --> </head>
<body>
    <article>
        <h1>An article about markup!</h1>
        <section  id="examele_1">
            <h1>Example 1</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="example 2">
            <h1>Example 2</h1>
        </section>
        <section data-subject="Example 3">
            <h1>Example 3</h1>
        </section>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

So: are any of examples 1 through 3 a good choice, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you are after, you should add role="region" to the section elements, like  so:

```
<section role="region">
```

This will tell the screen reader that the section is indeed a section, and will provide the correct accessibility information to the user. This role is an WAI-ARIA role. Ideally it would not be needed, as the section element has implied semantics, but there is better support for ARIA in screen readers than there is for HTML5 elements, so this plugs the gaps until support is widespread.

You can add the `aria-labelledby` attribute to the `section` element and associate it with the ID of the h* if you want the heading to be announced by the screen reader when it is announcing the section, such as “Example 1 region” in Jaws.

For each of your headings in the sections, it could be a good idea to include them in a `header` element too, like so, although not strictly needed (I often do it just for the main article heading)

```
<article role="article" aria-labelledby="title">
    <header>
        <h1 id="title">An article about markup!</h1>
   </header>
   <section role="region" aria-labelledby="eg1">
        <header>
             <h1 id="eg1">Example 1</h1>
        </header>
   </section>
   <section role="region" aria-labelledby="eg2">
        <header>
            <h1 id="eg2">Example 2</h1>
        </header>
    </section>
    <section role="region" aria-labelledby="eg3">
         <header>
            <h1 id="eg3">Example 3</h1>
         </header>
    </section>
```

For more information see http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2011/03/html5-accessibility-chops-section-elements/, http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/10/using-wai-aria-landmark-roles/ and http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/10/using-html5-section-element/

Comment: I was hoping that there might be a standard that goes further than this and solves for this section is about type of announces.

What I'd like to really have the user hear is "section||region about aesthetics, and then Section||Region about usability.  

It supports the pattern that we as users will say "on page x, in the section about y, it says z" so that discoveries can be shared easily.

If passing this job to header/h1 is the way to go, then that's a good solve except in the cases where a header doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CrispenSmith - If you want the screen reader to read out "section about" before the heading, you could put those words into an element before the heading, and use `text-indent` with a large negative value to shift it off the screen. However, I would not recommend it. It's almost always better to let the screen reader user receive exactly the same text that the sighted user does, along with whatever assistance the user-configured screen reader provides for them.

Comment: Actually, that's more or less exactly what my goal is;  sighted readers get a lot of visual cues that identify the nature of a section;  I just wanted to be sure that using a heading was the best way to share those visual cues in non-visual contexts; rather than augmenting it with a meta piece.  As I said above, being able to identify the location of a discovery in order to share it is a vital way to encourage conversation about content.  I fully agree that non-visible text is a bad idea and if the Header provides the signposts we need, I'm all for that.

Comment: I don't think you need what you are asking for. Screen readers can navigate via headings, so it will tell the user it is a section (via aria) and then they can navigate to the heading via the h* elements to find out what it is about. The natural semantics and aria attributes have everything the screenreader needs.

Comment: @CrispenSmith I’ve added an explanation of aria-labelledby, which should do what you want, as long as the heading text is sufficient.

Comment: I've just taken a quick read of it and while I can't comment on the older version I think the current version is quite good.

Answer (score 4):

I addition to dstorey's excellent advice, I would say that you **should not** use `<h1>` at each section level.

Although it was previously recommended, that recommendation has changed in HTML5 and now the advice is to use the `<h?>` level that works for the whole document. i.e. if the top level article uses an `<h1>` then the sections should use `<h2>`, the same as you would have done in HTML 4.

The reason is that using `<h1>` throughout depends on the implementation of the HTML5 outline algorithm. Unfortunately, it seems that browsers are unwilling to implement the algorithm, and the screen readers are either unwilling or unable to do so correctly. So nowhere in the accessibility tool chain is the outline being correctly processed and assistive device users will not be able to understand the heading levels correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I'd missed that spec update and was working off the older version.  The older version really does make more sense.

Comment: @CrispenSmith This update is in 5.1, which isn't released yet I think. Right now, it is more or less a "oops my bad" do this in an appendix. So I don't thinl you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible styling solution via CSS3 is shown below; you can modify it up to your needs. 
Here is a link to jsfiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/M6mpt/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<article class="article1">
<h1>An article about markup!</h1>
<section  class="section1">
<h1>Example 1</h1>
</section>
<section class="section2">
<h1>Example 2</h1>
</section>
<section class="section3">
 <h1>Example 3</h1>
 </section>
 </article>
 </body>
```

**CSS3**

```
.article1 {
    font-family: Arial;
}

.article1 h1 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.2em;
}

.section1 h1 {
    font-size:1.1em;
    color:#606060;
}

.section2 h1 {
    color:#909090;
}

.section3 h1 {
    color:#a0a0a0;
    font-size:0.9em;
}
```

Comment: I think I'm not getting your solution.  Am I missing the link between how this helps sighted readers and those requiring vision assistance?  Also, am I missing how this provides deep insight to the screen reader about what to announce?

Comment: Yeah, this one provides CSS3 styling via visual attributes of the on-screen content. Are you looking for some sort of text magnifiers, or Text-to-Speech converters? Please clarify, because I didn't quite get a spec requirements. Rgds,

Comment: I'm looking to solve for this:
"Screen-reader type assistive devices announce sections in an insightful way"  
and specifically this portion of it:
How do we mark up the &lt;section&gt; to empower assistive devices to pluck the section focus from the tag?

Both from the original question.